# Azure data factory data flow expression builder

Tags: azure-data-factory

Trying to pull data from source using query:

```
concat('select column_name from {$trytable} where table_name =',$scddimname)
```

Both parameters declared and value assigned as:

```
scddimname string 'emp_scd'
trytable string'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'
```

But, error

```
Error:
DF-DSL-001 - DSL stream has parsing errors
Line 9 Position 86: token recognition error at: '\n' - RunId: e93f18d2-cc0d-4b64-8336-15e75a5aaa22
```

Looks troubling!